# Symfony2 access_control with i18n routes

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization

I have a symfony2 project, where I have a section for logged in users. After internationalisation the site exists on 5 different languages. Because of the member area I have a long list of access_control rules in the security.yml and until this point I couldn't make the acl list easier and if a new language comes I have to add all of the acl rules again with the translated routes.
For example, the default route is /help what needs ROLE_USER but on german that route is /hilfe.

Is there an easier way to deal with this as copy the translated paths ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi is your web app only for logged in users?
In this case you can simply set access_control like this:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Or you can add prefix for your role. Means that everything matches /user/* is required ROLE_USER

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/user/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Hope it helps even its not the exact answer to your question

Answer (score 1):

as @jan Dockal say, you can use regular expression in path.
by regex you can set a role for any url that macth `^/user/` that want match `/user/help` and `/user/hilfe`.

but i suggest that you use [jms bundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle), with custom strategy

i hope that this help you :)

Comment: As i wrote i have a long list of access_control elements, not just admin and user, like 25 diff route patterns

Comment: I'm using i18n bundle, but I still don't see how is it relevant to my access_control question.

Comment: Sorry, but I specified that the ROUTES are translated, help to hilfe, and NOT prefixed with locale. It looks like a totally different app, different host, what I solved with the I18nRouting bundle, and I translated the routes there.